# ORDER BY IS INVALID

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I know youve answered similar issues before but I have a specific query I hope you can help.
I have a table of organizations (clients).
I need to find the most recent job per client.

the thing is, the client table isnt directly connected to the job. It goes like this Job - Job Header - Organization.

So I have a query for ALL Organizations (`Select * From Organizations`), then I have a JOIN to a query which finds the most recent job using the client ORg as the join criteria.

For 
example:

```
Select * From Organization
LEFT JOIN (Select Top 1 JobDate, JobNumber,JobWeight From Jobs LEFT JOIN JobHeader on Job.PK = JobHeader.ParentPK LEFT JOIN Organization on JObHeader.Org = Organization.PK Order by JObDate DESC)
```

When I ran it, it gives an error saying Order By clause is invalid in views, inline functions.

How else can I find the most recent JObDate in the JobHeader table for each related Organization?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks like SQL Server.  You can do what you want using a correlated subquery or lateral join (`apply`).  This looks like

```
select o.*, j.*
from Organization o outer apply
     (select Top 1 JobDate, JobNumber, JobWeight
      from Jobs j join
           JobHeader jh
           on j.PK = jh.ParentPK 
      where jh.Org = o.PK 
      order by JObDate DESC
     ) j;
```